# link_to action e id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mvc

Quero fazer um action para mudar o password e tenho o seguinte link_to para redirecionar para o *html.erb* com o usuário correto

```
<%= link_to 'Mudar Senha', "edit_password_form/" + @usuario.id.to_s %>
```

Sinto que estou fazendo da forma errada, qual o melhor jeito de se fazer isso?

Comment: Edite tua pergunta acrescentando mais detalhes. Tu está usando uma *gem* (como o Devise, por exemplo) para autenticação por usuário ou criou tudo "no braço" mesmo? Existe um `usuarios_controller.rb` criado por ti? Como está teu `routes.rb` até aqui?

Answer (score 1):

Verifique as suas rotas de seu projeto, dando o comando `rake routes` a partir do `console`, esse comando retornará uma lista com 4 colunas.

- A 4 coluna é a ação do seu controller que devera ser executada (ex:
  show).
- A 3 é a rota como é exibida na barra de endereços .
- A 2 é o método de envio usado pela ação.
- A 1 é o atalho para usar o
  redirecionamento.

Ache a ação que deseja usar no seu controller na 4 coluna e coloque no lugar do "edit_password_form/" + @usuario.id.to_s o que aparece na primeira coluna + path, caso precise especificar um objeto passe ele na função (ex: `edit_password_path(@usuario)`).

Caso a primeira coluna esteja vazia você deverá olhar o método dela, será o mesmo path da linha superior, mas precisará especificar o método com o atributo method (ex: `method: :put`)

Caso contrário, deve adicionar a rota em seu arquivo `routes.rb` (estude sobre)